# Linked Server To Progress Database Failing (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, odbc, openedge, progress-db

I have a linked server to a progress database. For the past week the connection was working and I was able to use the :

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('LinkedServerName', 'Query')
```

Code in order to run basic selects from the progress tables on that database. Suddenly today however it seems that the linked servers are no longer working. I checked by ODBC Drivers that connect to the Progress Database and they all seem to connect via the test connection. However when I go to test the linked server connection using that ODBC, the test connection hoses my entire instance of SSMS. This is a weird one. This is also on a production box so rebooting is a last resort. I've also determined that the progress DB's are up and running without issue.
I'm sort of an accidental DBA, and it's times like this when I get lost. Has anyone else run into a similar issue? What did you do to correct it?

Comment: SQL server 2008 is MSSQL not MySQL so ive removed the MySQL tag

Comment: Sorry, I must have clicked that tag by mistake @Raymod Nijland

Comment: Do you have an error message that is more detailed than "no longer working" or "hoses"?

Comment: The connection times out when running the SQL statement against the Linked Server, when the selecting the linked servers "Test Connection" option, the Instance of SSMS locks up. Will write down exact error. My apologies

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer I was looking for, but it ended up being an issue with the driver. I had to reboot the server, which appear to have freed the driver from whatever was locking it up. Now these queries will run and the connections establish. 
I still would like to see if anyone might have a better solution to help others in the future. As for an error message, I still have not been able to get a screen shot of it. The instance of SSMS locked up before I could.